# printf bug in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a status function but nothing except for the "Tracked:" is printing out. Can anyone see why? I'm assuming that the '.index' file is just a line by line list of file names.

```
int git_status() {

  FILE *check = fopen(".git/.index", "r");
  int count = 0;
  char *pointer;
  printf("Tracked:\n\n");
  while(fgets(pointer, sizeof(pointer), check)){
    strtok(pointer, "\n");
    printf("%s\n", pointer);
    count++;
  }
  printf("\n%d is the number of files", count);
  fclose(check);
}
```

Comment: Craaaaaank up the warnings. It'll pop right up.

Comment: Huh?            ..........

Comment: Ask yourself, How many characters is fgets reading and what memory are they going into?

Comment: In each iteration, it's reading til \n and they are stored into the 'pointer', overwriting the old 'pointer'. @ZanLynx

Comment: Steve, looks like you need to read the docs on fgets.

Comment: But what memory is the pointer pointing to?

Comment: And sizeof(a pointer) is 4 bytes on 32 bit or 8 on 64 bit, but in either case not what you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C you need to allocate the memory you want for strings.  In your case you need to declare either a array of characters with fixed length or dynamically reserve enough memory to contain the characters you are about to read.

For instance, the following is not very safe because p does not point to any memory, it is just an uninitialized address:

```
char* p;
strcpy(p, "This is a string");
```

If your lucky your compiler should warn you when you try to do things like the above (you might need to enable warnings, `-Wall` on gcc).

A better approach might be

```
char chArray[20];
strcpy(chArray, "This is a string");
```

or

```
char *p = malloc(20);
strcpy(p, "This is a string");
free(p);
```

As for `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream)` you probably want to do something like:

```
#define BUFFER 128

char buf[BUFFER];
while (fgets(buf, BUFFER, fp) != NULL) { /* TODO */ }
```

To get your program running you will also probably need to look at how `strtok` works:

> The strtok() function breaks a string into a sequence of zero  or 
>   more
>          nonempty tokens.  On the first call to strtok() the string to be parsed
>          should be specified in str.  In each subsequent call that should  parse
>          the same string, str must be NULL.

Comment: `p` is not an integer . suggest changing to "uninitialized address"

Comment: Note that the code in the question is using `strtok()` to zap the newline at the end of the string, assuming it is present.  It is an odd-ball but valid use of `strtok()` — inasmuch as any use of `strtok()` is ever valid.  It is most certainly not the conventional way to do the zapping, but it does work.